# Get values from nested array that are dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I am working on a chrome plugin that fetches data. But now i have been running into a problem, I have been asked to put together a nested array with all the data I have retrieved but I have no clue on how to pull this off.

**What i want to create:**

```
var messagedata [{
time: messageTime,
Date: messageDate,
Text: messageText
{
time: messageTime,
Date: messageDate,
Text: messageText
}
}];
```

**Note** that I know how to create the above when I have the variables. That is not the problem. But in this case i do not know how to declare the variables for each message from the array that is generated.

What i need is a nested array for each message that is in the HTML. So the above example displays 2 arrays but it could be 54 for example.

**Code i use to generate normal array:**

```
adiv.innerHTML = cleanupDocString;
  trs = adiv.querySelectorAll('tr[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"]');
  trs.forEach(function(tr) {
    var d = [];
    tr.querySelectorAll("td")
      .forEach(function(td) {
        var img = td.querySelector("img"),
          src = img && img.attributes.getNamedItem("src").value;
        d.push(src || td.textContent);
      });
    msgs.push(d);
  });
```

**The code above puts this out in console** (this example has 2 messages inside it, there are also arrays with 54 messages)**:**

> 1. 0:Array(6)
>
>    1. 0:"2017-08-31T00:00:00"
>    2. 1:"13:22"
>    3. 2:"MessageType"
>    4. 3:”ClientName"
>    5. 4:"Subject "
>    6. 5:"messageText"
>    7. length:6
>    8. **proto**:Array(0)
> 2. 1:Array(6)
>
>    1. 0:"2017-08-31T00:00:00"
>    2. 1:"13:21"
>    3. 2:" MessageType "
>    4. 3: "ClientName"
>    5. 4:" Subject "
>    6. 5:" messageText "
>    7. lenth:6
>    8. **proto**:Array(0)

To make the question easier: 
I need to know how i can put the data into a variable that i fetch from the array above. I just don't know how to do it so its dynamic.

**What i tried:**

```
var messageDate = msgs[0][0];
var messageTime = msgs[0][1];
var messageType = msgs[0][2];
var messageClient = msgs[0][3];
var messageSubject = msgs[0][4];
var messageText = msgs[0][5];
```

The above code works but only fetches the first message. I need all the messages that are on the page that is provided. I tried using a ID in the first [] but that also didn't give me the desired result.

Thanks for your help and patience in advance.

**Output and code has been slightly edited so it hides personal information**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am assuming msgs is arrray of arrays and the order of properties is guaranteed

```
var mappedArray = msgs.map((msg)=> {
   return {
      messageDate : msg[0];
      messageTime : msg[1];
      messageType : msg[2];
      messageClient : msg[3];
      messageSubject : msg[4];
      messageText :msg[5];
   } 
})
```

Edit1
  you can use array[concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
var mergedArray = mappedArray.concat(otherArray);
```

Comment: You have to remove the ; from behind the variables but after that it worked perfectly. I got 1 more question still, i got 2 arrays like this now and i want to join them together. But when i use messageData.push(mappedArray); it just gives me numbers in console. I technically want to add another array above all messages with those variables that i already have.

Comment: I've modified the answer is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I justed noticed i was responding on a different account haha

Answer (score 0):

To transform the multidimensional array to an array of objects with the help of [**Array.prototype.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a simple helper dictionary which defines the index => property mapping.

```js
var messages = [
  [
    "2017-08-31T00:00:00",
    "13:22",
    "MessageType",
    "ClientName",
    "Subject",
    "messageText",
    "unwanted value"
  ],
  [
    "2017-08-31T00:00:00",
    "13:22",
    "MessageType",
    "ClientName",
    "Subject",
    "messageText",
    "unwanted value"
  ],
  [
    "2017-08-31T00:00:00",
    "13:22",
    "MessageType",
    "ClientName",
    "Subject",
    "messageText",
    "unwanted value"
  ]
];

var mappingDef = { 
  0: 'messageDate',
  1: 'messageTime',
  2: 'messageType',
  3: 'messageClient',
  4: 'messageSubject',
  5: 'messageText'
};

function transformMessages(messages, mappingDef) {
  return messages.map(function(message) {
     var obj = {};
     for(var index in mappingDef) {
       if(mappingDef.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
         obj[mappingDef[index]] = message[index];
       }
     }
     return obj;
  });
}

console.log(transformMessages(messages, mappingDef));
```